# How can I add array of components to a new gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#

I use Getcomponents to get all components from existing gameobject:

```
Component[] components = go.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
```

And I want to add them now to another gameobject:

```
for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
                {
                    var comp = components[i];
                    newObject.AddComponent<comp>();
                }
```

components is type Component[]

But when I try to type components inside the AddComponent<> the variable components not exist. Tried then to make the comp variable but can't type it inside the <> either.

Comment: The type parameter (inside the angle brackets) can only be the name of a type known at compile time. You can't place a variable there. Have you tried passing your component types as arguments instead?

Comment: Yes right. newObject.AddComponent(components[i].GetType()); Thanks.

Comment: If you solved your problem, remember to post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: newObject.AddComponent(components[i].GetType());